# Styling table with lots of requirements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, styling, css-tables

I have such requirements for table

- 1st column min width 100px and dynamically resized if others requirements are fine
- 2nd column min width 155px and dynamically resized if others requirements are fine
- 3rd-5th columns min width 92px and dynamically resized if others requirements are fine
- all 5 column should fit whole available width (you can assume that 1200px on codepen  is that)

It looks like I am almost there but the last  what I have to do is to keep width of the columns in one color the same.

Here is what I did so far
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjYZwX

HTML

```
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="channel">Vasan</div>
    <div class="progress-cell">Subramanian asdasdasdasd</div>
    <div class="num" title="vasan@example.com">vasan@example.com</div>
    <div class="num">January 14, 1996</div>
    <div class="num">1,024</div>

  </div>

  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="channel">Firstnsdfsdfsdfa sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme sdfsdfsdme</div>
    <div class="progress-cell">Lastname</div>
    <div class="num" title="ns@example.org">ns@example.org</div>
    <div class="num">February 31, 1948</div>
    <div class="num">2,484</div>
  </div>

  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="channel">Example</div>
    <div class="progress-cell">McDude</div>
    <div class="num" title="N/A">--</div>
    <div class="num">December 31, 1960</div>
    <div class="num">0</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.total-width {
  width: 1200px;
}
.table-row {
  display: flex;           display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;     -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 0;            -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;         -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.channel {
  flex-grow: 1;            -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-right: 5px;
  max-width:100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  background: red;  
}

.progress-cell {
  flex-grow: 1;            -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width:100%;
  min-width: 155px;
  background: green;
}

.num {
  flex-grow: 1;            -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width:100%;
  min-width: 92px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

UPDATE

Maybe image below will show what I need
[image]

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I really didn't understand what you want to do

Comment: So one of the requirements is that the last three columns should have the same width? That can be arranged, but only with JavaScript.

Comment: Also, do you want the solution to look like the codepen, or like the example in your question? They're different.

Comment: What part of the requirements is not currently being met, and what behavior are you getting instead?

Comment: I am no able to resize column widths dynamically and meet minimum width requirement for all of them (please see attach image)